# SVG logo has different font on mobile than desktop

Tags: iphone, image, svg

[This SVG logo](https://www.insightdesign.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Insight-Hosting-Logo.svg) looks correct on a desktop browser like Chrome on a Mac:

[image]

The correctly displayed logo on desktop has the word "Hosting" in a sans-serif font.

However on an iPhone 5 & 7, the word "Hosting" is in a serif font:

[image]

What do I need to do to display the logo on mobile the same as on desktop please, so that the word "Hosting" is sans-serif?

Edit: the word "hosting" is not produced by paths like the rest of the logo, it is a `<text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 96.9229 18.4597)" class="st2 st3 st4">hosting</text>`.

How do I ensure the word hosting is produced by paths in Illustrator?

Answer (score 2):

I saw in the .ai file the text had not been converted to paths.

Type > Create Outlines > Export to SVG removed all text from the SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `<text>` over paths as you would be able to change the text that's inside of it and also i think it decompresses the file size (not sure about this).

You can add style to text so that it can be of any font that you have. Simply apply `font-family:Sans Serif;` to your `<text>` element, `class` attribute or `id` attribute.